# What is the best way to make a voting function on my website? (now using innerhtml

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Im making a prototype for a website. I want to showcase that the user can choose between three images and pick a favorite image.

I made it with innerhtml, to showcase the user has picked a favorite, the text changes. The problem is now you can vote as many times as you want. I want it to be that you can only pick one image.

```js
function myKeuze() {
  document.getElementById("keuzeVerhaal").innerHTML = "What is your favorite picture?";
}

function Sien() {
  document.getElementById("uitslag").innerHTML = "Your vote is: Sien!";
}

function Pien() {
  document.getElementById("uitslag").innerHTML = "Your vote is: Pino!";
}

function Aart() {
  document.getElementById("uitslag").innerHTML = "Your vote is: Aart!";
}
```

```html
<section id="Three" class="main style1 dark fullscreen">
  <div class="content container 75%">
    <header>
      <h2 id="uitslag">Choose your favorite</h2>
      <h3 id="keuzeVerhaal">Which picture do you like most??</h3>
    </header>
    <img src="sien.png" width="30%" onclick="myKeuze();Sien()" />
    <img src="pien.png" width="30%" onclick="myKeuze();Pien()" />
    <img src="aart.png" width="30%" onclick="myKeuze();Aart()" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a function that gets called on click called `stopVoting` this function once called will prevent the images from being clicked any further.

The method bellow works by looping through all the images and turning their `onclick` attribute to `null` that way clicking them will do nothing in the future.

```js
function myKeuze() {
  document.getElementById("keuzeVerhaal").innerHTML = "What is your favorite picture?";
}

function Sien() {
  document.getElementById("uitslag").innerHTML = "Your vote is: Sien!";
  stopVoting();
}

function Pien() {
  document.getElementById("uitslag").innerHTML = "Your vote is: Pino!";
  stopVoting();
}

function Aart() {
  document.getElementById("uitslag").innerHTML = "Your vote is: Aart!";
  stopVoting();
}
function stopVoting(){
 var images = document.querySelectorAll('#Three img');
 for( var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
     images[i].onclick = null;
 }

}
```

```html
<section id="Three" class="main style1 dark fullscreen">
  <div class="content container 75%">
    <header>
      <h2 id="uitslag">Choose your favorite</h2>
      <h3 id="keuzeVerhaal">Which picture do you like most??</h3>
    </header>
    <img src="sien.png" width="30%" onclick="myKeuze();Sien()" />
    <img src="pien.png" width="30%" onclick="myKeuze();Pien()" />
    <img src="aart.png" width="30%" onclick="myKeuze();Aart()" />
  </div>
</section>
```